# Arrow in jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, user-interface

Is there any way by which I can show an arrow tip on left of jQuery dialog? I would like to achieve functionality as mentioned in image below. How to do this with Theme roller CSS and icons?

[jQuery Dialog Customization http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/74b51bb861.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/74b51bb861.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: I posted my first answer BEFORE the edit was made, indicating that arrow was to be placed in the body of the dialog, so here is my updated code:

```
var $mydialog = $('<div></div>').html('<div class="myArrow"></div>Your Dialog Content Here').dialog({autoOpen: false,title: 'Retrieving Product Details', modal:true, width:600, height:400, position:'center'});
```

The myArrow div has been moved to the main content div of the dialog, CSS could be something like:

```
.myArrow{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  left:-15px; /* pushes the arrow OUTSIDE the box */
  top:50px; /* or however far from the top you wish */
  background: url(path/to/arrow.jpg) center right no-repeat;
  margin:0 15px 0 0;
  }
```

Comment: dunno if this will help anyone but I had to override .ui-dialog with overflow: visible, set to hidden by default in jquery-ui 1.8.20

Comment: Also need it on .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content as well

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be t simply add the html and / or css into your title attribute when constructing your dialog like so:

```
var $mydialog = $('<div></div>').html('Your Dialog Content Here').dialog({autoOpen: false,title: '<div class="myArrow"></div>Retrieving Product Details', modal:true, width:600, height:400, position:'center'});

$mydialog.dialog('open'); //triggers dialog open event, can close with ('close')
```

And the css for myArrow:

```
.myArrow{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background: url(path/to/arrow.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  margin:0 15px 0 0; // some maring on the right to push title away from div;
  }
```

Hope that helps a little

Comment: While this is not CUSTOMIZING the actual dialog itself, it is a simple method and ensures that multiple instances of a dialog can have different arrows for example.